# How to add CI whiskers to a rarefaction curve

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I need to make some rarefaction curves and I wish them to display the whiskers at the edges of the confidence interval bars, whereas the default is to simply display the bars without whiskers:

```
library(vegan) 
data("dune")
result <- specaccum(dune)
plot(result, lwd=2)
```

> [image: Default rarefaction curve]
>   **Default rarefaction curve**

I've tried to add some whiskers using the `arrows` function, but the results from the `specaccum` function only include the standard deviation. So I ended up with half the job done:

```
samples <- result$sites
error <- result$sd
richness <- result$richness
arrows(samples, richness-error, samples, richness+error, angle=90, code=3, length=0.05)
```

> [image: Rarefaction curve with sd whiskers]
>   **Rarefaction curve with sd whiskers**

From what I've searched, the most common approach would be to convert the confidence intervals into a shaded area (by using the argument `ci.type="polygon"`) and then add a `boxplot` to the plotted curve. However, this leads to a very busy image that I'd rather avoid.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the multiplier (see argument `ci` in `?plot.specaccum`). What you drew were for a ~68% confidence interval. Multiplying by 2 (`ci = 2`) gives an approximate 95% confidence interval, which is what `plot.specaccum` draws by default.

Including the (default) multiplier in a modification of the code you used

```
plot(result)
with(result, arrows(sites, richness - (2 * sd), sites, richness + (2 * sd),
                    angle = 90, code = 3, length = 0.05))
```

we get:

[image]

You can ignore the warning; the standard error of the last data point drawn is zero

```
> result$sd
 [1] 2.3510636 1.8763851 1.5722711 1.4469584 1.3901594 1.3530349 1.3164796
 [8] 1.2749034 1.2282010 1.1763410 1.1193437 1.0564537 0.9874094 0.9115998
[15] 0.8286890 0.7380921 0.6333903 0.5139710 0.3570714 0.0000000
```

and `arrow()` is just warning you that it won't draw a length 0 arrow.

Comment: Glad to see that I was close to reach a solution.
Cheers!

Comment: Currently we use `segments` to draw the error bars. We could switch to `arrows(..., code = 3, angle = 90)`, but that would require adding argument `ci.len` to set the length of vertical end bars (with default `ci.len = 0`). Would this be desirable?

Answer (score 1):

you could try to add a plotCI-plot:

```
library(vegan) 
library(plotrix) 
data("dune")
result <- specaccum(dune)

plot(result)
plotCI(result$sites,result$richness,result$sd*2,err="y", lwd=2,add=TRUE, pch=NA)
```

I admit this is also not the most elegant option as well but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The **vegan** repository in [github](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/) has now an option for drawing those short horizontal bars to the error bars with argument `ci.length`. The default is zero (no horizontal bars) to preserve the old behaviour.